# css media query issue

Tags: css, media-queries

I am new to html conversion.Now i am converting a design into full responsive website using bootstrap,css and html.
    In my css I have included a code like
CSS:

```
    @media screen (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 414px) {
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: white;
    }
}
and

   @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

the problem i am facing is that the first query is not working can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: Not working in so much as the screen stays red all the time?

Comment: From the width  600px and below ,the background color of the body becomes red.And the  background color of the body stays red from 320px to 414px even though i have written the query to change the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is working if we put it after the second query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 414px) {
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here doing wrong below code will helo you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 414px) {
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: white;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)and (min-width: 414px) {
body {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>resize width between 320px 414px change color yellow else less then 600px it will change red</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use " @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 414px) "  instead of "@media screen (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 414px)"

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see it now. The second rule will always "beat" the first. In the first rule you specify yellow for 320-414, but in the second rule you contradict that statement by saying you want red from 0-600.

Reverse the order of the queries and importantly you are missing an "and"!

Comment: thank you sir.Now i understood the mistakes in my query

Comment: No problem, you can mark the answer correct if it helped you.